# Is it possible to append to the next column horizontally in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-data-api

I currently have this script. I works fine, however, I would prefer if it **appended to the next column horizontally** each time a choose to append. Right now it appends after the last row. Please be very specific about what needs changing. Thanks!

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aACg8M89LLxILIvUqWT2ZnrykF8e3BkIiamj2NhKrmc")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Framsida");
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 25, 1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(data[i][0]);
    Logger.log(data[i][1]);
  }
  var row= sheet.getLastRow();
 Logger.log(row);
 Logger.log(data);
   var temp = data
     for (i in temp){
       var write = temp[i]
       if (row >=10) {ss.getSheetByName("Archive").appendRow(write)};

     } 
   ss.getSheetByName("Framsida").getRange(2, 3, 25, 1).clear();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve the values from the cells of "C2:C26" on the sheet "Framsida", and want to put the values to the next column of the last column on the sheet "Archive".

In order to retrieve the last column of the sheet, please use `getLastColumn()`. Here, I would like to propose 2 patterns for achieving your goal.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `getValues` and `setValues` are used.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aACg8M89LLxILIvUqWT2ZnrykF8e3BkIiamj2NhKrmc")
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Framsida"); // <--- Modified
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(2, 3, 25, 1);
  var data = srcRange.getValues();
  
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  dstSheet.getRange(2, dstSheet.getLastColumn() + 1, data.length, 1).setValues(data);
  
  srcRange.clear();
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `copyTo` is used.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1aACg8M89LLxILIvUqWT2ZnrykF8e3BkIiamj2NhKrmc")
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Framsida"); // <--- Modified
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange(2, 3, 25, 1);
  
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  srcRange.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(2, dstSheet.getLastColumn() + 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
  
  srcRange.clear();
}
```

- When `srcRange.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(2, dstSheet.getLastColumn() + 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);` is modified to `srcRange.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(2, dstSheet.getLastColumn() + 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, true);`, the values are put by transposing.

  - If `appended to the next column horizontally` means that you want to horizontally put the values from "C2:C26" to the last column by transposing, please test this.

### References:

- [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

Comment: I tried both the scripts, however, I got the same error on both: `ReferenceError: srcSheet is not defined (rad: 4, fil: Kod)`. My operating system is in Swedish, hence "rad" and " kod". They mean "Row" and "Code". I don't know if this is my fault?

Comment: I believe you have understood the question totally correct.

Comment: Hello @PhilipHegardt, you will just have to rename the `var sheet` to `var srcSheet`. Cheers!

Comment: @Philip Hegardt Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I noticed that my script includes the wrong parts. I had forgot that I had replaced the variable name from `sheet` to `srcSheet`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So I updated it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @ale13 Thank you so much for your support. I could notice about it and modify the script.